# Api call to another container doesn't work in blazor wasm

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly, docker-network

I have a project whose schema is like this :

[image]

When blazor webassembly published output, which exists in **client_container**(nginx alpine image), calls api, which is up in **api_container**, nothing happens.

And it couldn't receive any data.

The worse thing is that, blazor client_container doesn't provide me with any error.

Opening the page on my PC : http://localhost:8081/

The working result should be like this :

[image]

BUT it works like this :

[image]

The API call in razor component is this :

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // in Debugging
    //people = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Person>>("http://localhost:8080/api/people");

    // in Publish in Docker
    people = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Person>>("http://api_container/api/people");
}
```

These are docker run commands :

```
docker run -p 8080:80 --rm --name api_container --network store_network parsalotfy/store_api
docker run -p 8081:80 --rm --name client_container --network store_network parsalotfy/store_client
```

To test if the api is accessible in client_container, I did such a test :

```
docker exec -it client_container sh
```

then in nginx client_countainer :

```
/usr/share/nginx/html # curl http://api_container/api/people
```

this is the result :

[image]

**It is odd that api is accessible in client_container but the api call in razor component fails.**

and this is client_container log :

[image]

You can take a look at all the code here in [github](https://github.com/parsalotfy/UniProject_Store) in case you are interested

Sorry if it was too boring :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this in mind that you're using Blazor WASM which runs on client side just like JavaScript, I should note that all the requests including api calls (`/api/people`) are executed in the client browser & machine and they're browser can't resolve a host named `api_container` so unsurprisingly any request to your api and `api_container` will fail.

Comment: It was a mind blowing point ! Thank you very much it worked !!! I thought because it is running in container it's network is on the container too !